# How to handle javascript scope

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

I've got a simple javascript loop and a function with a callback in there and I'm struggeling with adding

```
console.log(accounts);  // logs this: ["123", "456"]
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
  var currentAccount = accounts[i];
  console.log(currentAccount);  // first logs "123" and then "456" as expected

  meta.getBalance.call(account, {from: currentAccount}).then(function(value) {
    console.log(currentAccount);  // logs "456" twice
    console.log(value.value());  // logs the same value corresponding to "123" twice
  });
}
```

I presume that it logs "456" twice within the callback because it is an async call or something. But I'm unsure how I can solve this.

Any idea?

[EDIT]

I added one more `console.log` to it, which logs the value returned by the callback. To my surprise, that logs the same value twice, which corresponds to 123, instead of to 456. WHY OH WHY?! How in godsname can that be?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
function cbGenerator(account) {
  return function(value) {
    console.log(account);
  }
}
```

Later...

```
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
  var currentAccount = accounts[i];
  console.log(currentAccount);  
  var cb = cbGenerator(currentAccount);
  meta.getBalance.call(account, {from: currentAccount}).then(cb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function inside IIFE

```js
console.log(accounts);  // logs this: ["123", "456"]
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
  var currentAccount = accounts[i];
  console.log(currentAccount);  // first logs "123" and then "456" as expected

  (function(currentAccount){
         meta.getBalance.call(account, {from:currentAccount}).then(function(value) {
    console.log(currentAccount);  
          });    
  })(currentAccount);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your current value to a function, that return a function that gets called and has access to your value. Thats called [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
var accounts = ["123", "456"];
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
  var currentAccount = accounts[i];
  console.log(currentAccount);  // first logs "123" and then "456" as expected

  promise('account', {from: currentAccount}).then(currentAccount => res => {
        console.log(currentAccount) // 123, then 456
  });
}

function promise() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => res());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback you log the `currentAccount` variable, which comes from the outer scope and is being assigned in the for loop.

Most likely, when your async call returns from its first call (made when currentAccount was "123"), currentAccount has already taken the value of the 2nd array element "456" inside the for loop.

Can you try to log the `value` argument passed to the callback instead? You should see 2 distinct values being returned, one for account "123" and another for account "456".

Comment: I realize I did not actually give you an aswer to the concrete problem of logging the currentAccount from the callback. The aswer is in the use of closures, as @yarons and the others above suggested.